# Substitute "mma" (instead of "math") when limiting the list for off-topic migrations to Mathematica

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-tools, alias

In coming across a question to be migrated to [Mathematics](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com), I accidentally migrated the question to the newly-out-of-private-beta [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) site.

This happened because when migrating to Mathematics, I used to just type "math" in the dialog for "off topic".

However, typing "math" in the "off topic" dialog box reduces the results two four options, the first being the Mathematica site:

[image: Off-topic for "math"]

Given that the Mathematica community uses "mma" as shorthand for Mathematica, let us use the same shorthand when migrating to Mathematica, and have "math" filter down to one choice.

(Note: I'm open to other options on this, as the general issue is the fact that "Mathematica" and "Mathematics" differ on the *last* letter and it's a pain point in the off-topic dialog).

Comment: It's not a solution, but a helpful thought for now would be to look at the logo instead of the name. Maths has a distinct logo.

Comment: @GraceNote I agree, better observation would have prevented this in the first place.  I predict that the names being so similar are going to bring up various little pain points like these.

Comment: At the risk of sounding sassy: suck it up and pay attention. It's one extra second that means some poor moderation team doesn't have to deal with mistaken migrations.

Comment: I'm suggesting a red octagon for the Mathematica logo so we can easily tell it from Mathematics' red hexagon.

Comment: How about including the sub-domain names in the search? Then `math` would be an exact match for `math.se`, while `mathe` would match `mathematica.se`.

Comment: @hammar Pretty sure URLs are already included. IME, the search works for both site names and URLs, so `mathe` would match both Math and MMA anyway.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Then it just needs to rate exact URL matches higher than partial title matches.

Comment: @BilltheLizard +1!

Comment: What would happen when Mixed Martial Arts gets an SO site? CHAOS!

Comment: @CanSpice I imagine that would just fall under the [martial arts proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4470/martial-arts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make yourself a new five letter nickname for Mathematics, I propose

> atics

[image: Only the correct sites listed]

Comment: What happens when the "attics" proposal comes out of private beta and then I miss a "t"?

Comment: @casperOne chances are slim you will need to migrate a html parser check to a site about forgotten photos and paranormal activity

Comment: I've actually done this twice today, works like a charm.  It's only a workaround, and I think there's a general feature request here, but for now, this is keeping me from having to remove my hands from the keyboard.

Answer (score 11):

Mathematica needs to be listed when you input "Math", because, well, it's in the name. Search is based off of both the name and the URL - so that's why both `motor` and `mechanics` will get you Motor Vehicle & Maintenance (which is at mechanics.stackexchange.com).

The most you could hope for in this direction is that `mma` could also lead to Mathematica, but there isn't really a chance that it should not return Mathematica when searching for any substring of its name (which includes `math`) - this betrays both functionality and expectations. However, that is somewhat dependent on getting mma into the URL or otherwise of Mathematica. And it won't solve the problem you're actually running into.

One thing, not sure on the feasibility, but it might be nice to **prioritize the listing of options with a full-name or full-URL match**. In that way, entering `math` would list `math.stackexchange` (Mathematics) first. Short of changing the order, though, I don't know much which could be done.