# What should we do with the [alias] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

Since we've been seeing some meta-tag discussion these past few days, here's another:
What should we do with the six-question wiki-less [alias](/questions/tagged/alias) tag?

It seems to have been used as a synonym of [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms), but the questions arise: Should it be formally synonymized, or would simply retagging do? Or does it have some sort of unique use that I'm missing?

Comment: Two questions are about [site aliases](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site): [Substitute "mma" (instead of "math") when limiting the list for off-topic migrations to Mathematica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120719/241919), [Adding ethics as an alias for philosophy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304065/241919)

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any value in this tag, the existing [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) tag covers it well enough.

No need to synonymize either in my opinion, only six questions, it can be safely burninated. (Replaced with the better tag where missing.)